# Tokenizing commas with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Please explain these two lines of Perl from [this code](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/3a0631a05b7f53a7f387ca8ddca432f5ddb22029/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl#L280-L286).

```
# separate out "," except if within numbers (5,300)
# previous "global" application skips some:  A,B,C,D,E > A , B,C , D,E
# first application uses up B so rule can't see B,C
# two-step version here may create extra spaces but these are removed later
# will also space digit,letter or letter,digit forms (redundant with next section)
$text =~ s/([^\p{IsN}])[,]/$1 , /g;
$text =~ s/[,]([^\p{IsN}])/ , $1/g;
```

Comment: Given the edits to the question and title, it is no longer possible to truthfully select a single correct answer among the two. Thanks again though for both answers! :-)

Comment: I don't see how the edit affects that? It only cleaned up the unneeded verbiage and left your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does two replacements. The `s///` is a substitution, and the `/g` flag tells it to do it *globally*, which essentially is *replace all*.

Both lines make use of the [`\p{}` unicode property character groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html#Properties-accessible-through-%5Cp%7B%7D-and-%5CP%7B%7D) in the regular expression. With `IsN` it checks if the character is a number.

```
/            
 (           # capture group
  [          # character group
   ^         # not the following characters
   \p{IsN}   # all characters that are a number
  ]
 )
 [,]         # followed by a comma
/
```

It replaces that with the captured not numbers, a space, a comma and a space.

The second line does the same, but with the comma first.

You can rewrite this code to be shorter and more concise with the same features. The `\P{}` is *all chars that do not have this property*, which removes the need for `[]`. This can be shortened further to `\PN`.

```
$text =~ s/(\PN),/$1 , /g;
$text =~ s/,(\PN)/ , $1/g;
```

Comment: `\p{IsN}` ⇒ `\pN`, so `[^\p{IsN}]` ⇒ `\PN`.

Comment: what is the difference between `\p{IsN}` and `\d+` ?

Comment: @Flying_whale, For starters, `\pN` aka `\p{IsN}` aka `\p{General_Category: Numeric}` only matches a single code point.

Comment: @Flying_whale, `\d` is equivalent to `\p{Nd}` aka `\p{General_Category: Decimal_Number}`, the subset of `\pN` that are decimal digits. `\pN` includes 328 more Code Points that are numeric, but not decimal digits (e.g.  ¼, ㉑, etc)

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace all commas preceded by a character that doesn't have the "Number" Unicode General Category with `␠,␠`.
2. Replace all commas followed by a character that doesn't have the "Number" Unicode General Category with `␠,␠`.

Well, not quite. Because a comma is itself a non-numeric character, the above doesn't accurately describe what happens when there are two commas in a row.

But it's not worth going into too much detail because it doesn't work well since `A,B` becomes `A␠␠,␠␠B`.

Tokenizer:

```
my @tokens;
for ($text) {
   if (/\G ( (?: [^,\d]++ | \d(?:,\d++)*+ )++ ) /xgc) {
      push @tokens, [ TEXT => $1 ];
      redo;
   }

   if (/\G , /xgc) {
      push @tokens, [ 'COMMA' ];
      redo;
   }

   if (/\G \z /xgc) {
      push @tokens, [ 'EOF' ];
      last;
   }

   die("Internal error\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, they take care of that redundant spacing that ensues, in the remainder of the source file where this single stage belongs.